# Loop DoCmd.SendObject

Tags: ms-access

I volunteer for a charity helping them with their Access (2016) membership database, having stepped in when the creator passed away.  I am fairly experienced at using the program from the front end and have made many changes to improve how it works but unfortunately I'm a complete novice at VBA.

They would like to automate sending a unique statement to each of their 1500 members with a calculation of their class fees for the year.  Of course it is easy to do this individually, but automating the sending is proving more problematic to me.  I have looked at multiple similar(ish) solutions online and tried a variety of VBA codes but without luck.  And I feel it must be possible....

I have set up a simple dummy database to practise on and have some data in tblDawn.  A query picking up the contents of the table qryDawn.  A Form with a button to carry out the command.  A report rptDawn with data from qryDawn, which I want to send with the data particular to the individual.

Here's my code - but honestly I have got really lost with all the changes I have tried, so it is probably nonsensical now!

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
'Create listing of email addresses
strSQL = "SELECT tblDawn.ID, tblDawn.Email, tblDawn.Statement, tblDawn.Class, tblDawn.Amount FROM tblDawn"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

'Loop
With rs
     .MoveFirst
     Do While Not .EOF
         'assign ID for current record
          Me.ID = .Fields("tbl.ID")
          DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "rptDawn", acFormatPDF, .Fields("EMail"), , , "Satement", "Here is your statement attached", False
          .MoveNext
     Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help at all?  It is for a good cause!
TIA :)

Comment: This should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151196/ms-access-loop-through-query-recordsets-rows-and-output-results-as-an-excel-atta -- Open preview **with WHERE clause (ID)**, SendObject, Close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS access conditional content of report for DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629207/ms-access-conditional-content-of-report-for-docmd-sendobject-acsendreport)

Comment: Thank you for these answers, I will give them a go and report back.

Comment: Thank you so much Andre, your suggested solution worked really well.  I have been tinkering with this for over a year, so I am delighted and am extremely grateful for your help!!!